# java program command line execution

Tags: java

I am using UBUNTU 11.0.7 with softwares JDK7, but when iam trying to execute a simple java program from command line it again asks me to install jdk version , can anyone please help me out..

Comment: So install jdk from ubuntu software center, I believe ubuntu ships java inheritly

Comment: check the environment variables' path. are they pointing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

after install your jdk and set your path variable, write java -version to know that is java installed properly
then run your .jar file with java -jar yourfilePath